# Dispose DbContext not dispose the ObjectContext entities

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, dispose, dbcontext

I'm using EF 5.0 to create a web and I have some issues disposing my context. All the times that I use a context is inside a using sentence, so the context should be disposed automatically but in a specific moment I get the next error when I try to attach an entity to a context:

An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

It semms that the entity is not disposed. How is the way to manage this situation? Do I have to dispose the ObjectContext to dispose the entities or is there any way to check if the Entity is attached?

Regards.

Comment: Where do you get this attaching entity from? From the same context?

Comment: No, from another context. I always créate a new context inside a using sentence.

Comment: I think the same enitity (with the same key) already exists in the other context.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is what is happening, the other entity exist on the Objectcontext but I thougth that disposing the dbContext all the entities were detached from the ObjectContext.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to detach the existing object before attaching.  I don't have VS in front of me so I apologize if the code isn't exactly correct.

```
var existingObject = dbContext.Users.Local
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.id = newObject.id);

if (existingObject != null)
{
  // remove object from local cache
  dbContext.Entry(existingObject).State = EntityState.Detached;
}

dbContext.Users.Attach(newObject);
```

In case this doesn't fix the problem, you'll have to go to the old way of detaching objects.

```
  // remove object from local cache
  ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
  objectContext.Detach(existingObject);
```

Comment: In EF 5 the method Detach does not exist and with this code you are checking the entity on a specific dbContext, but the entity could be attached to another different dbcontext and the error should be the same.

Comment: Updated to EF5.  This should detach the object, but let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, this Works but I was trying to avoid a Detach because If I use this approach, when I should to execute the detach method? One when I créate a new object after an Add operation and the other after I attached manually the entity but, is there any more time that I should detach an object? Do you know any way to check if an entity is attached? The first code just check if the entity is attached on the current context but It could be that the entity was attached to another context.

Comment: An attached object may or may not be the same as what is in your database (this a big gotcha sometimes).  The question is, why would you be re-creating an already existing row/object, instead of updating it?

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like that:

```
User u;
using (Entities ent = new Entities())
{
    u = ent.Users.Single(a => a.ID == 123);
}
using (Entities ent2 = new Entities())
{
    //loading the same user
    User user2 = ent2.Users.Single(a => a.ID == 123);

    //trying to attach the same object with the same key
    ent2.Attach(u);
}
```

then you will get this error (*I haven't tested this code*).

EDIT: one of the solutions is to change the object's state:

```
ent2.Attach(u);
ent2.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(u, EntityState.Modified);
```

another solution is to check if the entity is already attached:

```
ObjectStateEntry state = null;
if(!ent2.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)u).EntityKey, out state))
{
    ent2.Attach(u);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but I'm doing this operation in different classes and is not to obvious to know if the class is in the context.

Comment: I haven't the property ObjectStateManager in Entity Framework 5 or I don't know where is it.

Comment: ent.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: I have tried it but I get an error casting my Entity to IentityWithKey.

Comment: You should have posted your code here. Where do you get your entities? From database or create in code?

Comment: I can't post the code because it's very extensive but I'm creating the entity from code and in another method I'm changing it with some other entities attached to this one that I have created but as I thougth that when I dispose the context all the entities should be disposed, I'm trying to attach the entity that I have created before to another new context and this is when I get the error.

Comment: If you create entities from your code you should realize `IEntityWithKey` yourself.

Comment: Ok, and what I have to do with the EntityKey property? do you have an example?

Comment: For example, `EntityKey userKey = new EntityKey("Entities.Users", "UserID", 123);`

Answer (score 0):

`Dispose` doesn't mean "reset to factory settings". It is a way to clean up unmanaged resources like database connections and such.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with disposing a context or not. It even has nothing to do with having multiple contexts somewhere in place. If this would be the problem you would get the "*An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker*" exception which is totally different to your exception.

You can simulate your exception quite easily with only a single context:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var customer1 = new Customer { Id = 1 };
    var customer2 = new Customer { Id = 1 }; // a second object with the same key

    ctx.Customer.Attach(customer1);
    ctx.Customer.Attach(customer2); // your exception will occur here
}
```

The problem causing this exception is normally more hidden, expecially if you keep in mind that attaching or setting a state (for example to `Modified`) will also attach all related entities in the object graph of the entity you are attaching. If in this graph are two objects with the same key you'll get the exception as well, although you didn't attach those related entities explicitly.

But it's impossible to find the exact reason without more details about your code.